Mantra-saṃskāra need to be done one time or everytime before reciting the main mantra?
I read about 10 saṃskāra's like deepan,bodhan, tadan etc. Do you have to perform samskaras before everyday or its just one time? For example in deepan samskara I read that you have to do 1000 japa with some modifications in the mantra. So is the 1000 japa one time only or everyday.

You should add a bit more context, where did you read this at? For example.
